# JavaScript variable as a function and getting data returned

Tags: javascript

Here's my JS snippet, which is all part of a VAR call.

```js
                    $showNextMonth,
                    $showNextMonthFunction = new function() {
                        if ($monthsLeft <= 9) {
                            $showNextMonth = '+1'
                        } else {
                            $showNextMonth = '0'
                        }
                    },
```

As you can see, i'm population `$showNextMonth` based of the `IF` condition. While this works, it seems sloppy. How could i use a Return, an then just use `$showNextMonthFunction` where i need to.

I'm sure this is a dupe, but i couldn't find a fit, so if there is one, please let me know.

Comment: Remove the `new` as you're assigning a function to a variable, not creating an instance of a object.

Comment: Are you sure using strings of numbers is the best way of doing it?

Comment: I need the string, as the jqueryUI datepicker needs a string when modifing the date range. to change the year range it's like -10:+3. So 10 back, and 3 forward type of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$showNextMonthFunction = function() {
    return ($monthsLeft <= 9 ? "+1" : "0");
 }();
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hitting a wall using return as i kept getting an object.

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: What do the trailing parentheses do?

Comment: unless you include trailing parentheses, function is consider as an value for the var and will return your whole function as a string. When you hit trailing parentheses, JS will consider it as a function and will return your value from logic inside the function block. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. That's why i switch from using Return. Helps alot!

Answer (score 1):

Much simplier :

`showNextMonth = monthsLeft <= 9 ? '+1' : '0';`

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question you want something like this:

```
$showNextMonthFunction = function() {
    return ($monthsLeft <= 9 ? "+1" : "0");
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$showNextMonthFunction = function() {
    if ($monthsLeft <= 9) 
        return '+1';
    return '0';
}
```

Comment: While this answer provides source code, it should also include some narrative to describe the answer.